# Does Cycles calculate 0 factor shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

If you have a material with shader nodes that are at 0 factor in a mix, does cycles still have to spend time processing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, cycles doesn't have to spend time rendering those nodes:

> Unnecessary shader inputs inside the Mix Shader are now ignored, in case the factor is 0.0 / 1.0 and not connected.

Also if a node branch is not connected to output, that branch is skipped. So for example when you have a node group outputting multiple shaders, it calculates only the connected ones:

[image]

Or:

[image]

This way you don't have to use Mix node "0/1 switches" and you can keep your node group count low and organised.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've read somewhere that optimizations are made internally at render time before rendering scene to skip these sort of things

<s>Very low (close to zero) or extremely high (close to 1)</s> 0.0 and 1.1 values are skipped to improve performance. (could find evidence of rounding values, maybe I misread or was wrong about that one)

These probably include shaders, mix values, roughness, emissions, fully black or white textures, etc.

Here are a few examples, there are probably a lot more:

https://developer.blender.org/rCfb7d4b2269b3edd44df869854f58962c2f051b07
https://developer.blender.org/rBS2c58e96685e80e4e12dfad56ed3bb51fa3824197
https://developer.blender.org/rBcbffc7499ef89cac19c07ee2116b8e1e5d38afe5

Comment: please add a reference for "close to zero" and "close to 1" if you are sure. Imho there is no such thing as rounding values to skip them!

Comment: Yeah couldn't find any either, maybe I'm wrong on that one, fixed the answer